# C# How can I check if the TimeOfDay is equal to a specified string time

Tags: c#, windows-services

Basically, I am developing a windows service and I'm asking the computer: if it is xx:xx:xx.xxx then do something.

Unfortunately I'm could not compare it to System.TimeSpan.Parse():

```
timer = new Timer();
this.timer.Interval = 100;
if ((DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == System.TimeSpan.Parse("02:30:00"))) //24-Hour
{
    //do something
    this.timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Also, is there a way to keep the service on watch if the the conditions are met and do the code in the if-block without a timer? or do you really need the timer.

Comment: You don't want to invent a scheduler yourself. What if your application is so busy that it won't process timer messages for a second? What if it is restarted during a time when a job had to be started? Anyway for your problem, "not getting any luck" is not really descriptive. Did you inspect the variables, or have you added log statements to see what the actual values are and why they don't match your expectations?

Comment: You should use a scheduler. I'm using Quartz.NET in a project and it's working fine.

Comment: You're very seldom going to line up exactly on zero milliseconds with a 100 millisecond timer interval. This will cause your comparison as given to fail. Try `[DateTime]::Now.AddMilliseconds(0 - [DateTime]::Now.Millisecond).TimeOfDay` for the left side of your comparison.

Comment: I updated the question. But still System.TimeSpan.Parse("02:20") is not comparing to DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay. Even if I added timespan to addwatch it says, cannot evaluate. I'll probably make it in a range from 02:00 to 03:00

Answer (score 1):

You're very seldom going to line up exactly on zero milliseconds with a 100 millisecond timer interval. This will cause your comparison as given to fail. Try `[DateTime]::Now.AddMilliseconds(0 - [DateTime]::Now.Millisecond).TimeOfDay` for the left side of your comparison.

Also, have you considered just making this a Windows Console app and firing it using Windows Scheduled Tasks? Sometimes that's a better option than writing a service.

Comment: But which is much more reliable. What if I made it into a time range? would that work?

Comment: Yes, you could do a ranged comparison. Remember that no matter what comparison you use, you'll need to guard against having the task fire multiple times. You'll need a mechanism to track if the task has already fired in the defined interval and skip execution if it has. Coded and configured properly firing a console app from the Task Scheduler is just as reliable as a service. In fact, it's likely to be simpler and more reliable than writing your own scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

> > You can use Quartz.NET library which is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems. It is very useful and easy to use.

[Here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/index.html) you can get some tutorials about this.

You can specify your desired schedule by defining a cron expression which is very flexible.

[Here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) is some documentation of this.

Answer (score 0):

if you saying `02:30:00` is the time in 24 format like `HH:mm:ss`

you can use like

```
if("02:30:00".Equals(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
{
// C# code goes here if both matchs
}
```

**update**

> DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

this will return only **hours:minutes:seconds**

Comment: What about the date? I only need the time to be checked.

Comment: yes it will check the time only.  it will check if today's time is `02:30:00` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answer. But, I have decided to do a ranged comparison.

```
timer = new Timer();
this.timer.Interval = 60000;
if(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= System.TimeSpan.Parse("03:00:00") && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= System.TimeSpan.Parse("03:30:00")) { //do something }
```